# How to bundle html, js and css in one .js file?

Tags: javascript

I have simple app with index.html, style.css and app.js and 
i need to built a myBundle.js for easy implemantation in other site like:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="myBundle.js"></script>
```

is that posible ?

Comment: What's the intention behind this?

Comment: It's possible to pack it into a HTML, and many tools exist for it (the simplest probably being parcel.js); and while it's also possible to pack into a JS file, there's not much point as something will need to execute it.

Comment: Yes, there are a few different bundlers out there.  https://webpack.js.org/   https://rollupjs.org to name a few.

Comment: Hey, did you find a way to do it? I would love to fins the solution, looked all the tutorials and nothing end up with a bundle.js file only.

Answer (score 0):

You can bundle it all inside the HTML file if you'd like. That would be the easiest way to make it portable

So for example:
    **yourfile.html**

```
<html>
  <head>
  <style type="text/css">
  /* your CSS */
  </style>
  <script type="text/js">
  // your JS code
  </script>
  </head>
  <body></body>
 </html>
```

Then you can move the file anywhere and it will work independently.

As mentioned below this is not a clean way to code but it will work and is useful in some instances

Comment: You could, however you'd violate SRP and SoC.

Comment: Agreed but it's a working solution and it could be just for a demo or something

Answer (score 0):

That's not a good idea, but maybe you can create elements in js and then use `append()` method to put your HTML / CSS